# Plugins registered for email entity is not triggered

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

While i click the email send, i have triggered the plugin with post condition and message as send,setEntity and SetStateDynamicEntity to trigger plugin to update current email sending activity date in the custom field as last activity. While i send normal mail it triggers and update the field, if i send with an attachment in email this plugin not getting triggered. even though i changed the steps from post to Pre-condition it not working. Sometimes it working automatically and sometimes it was not working.

Comment: You have to check the code for any **return** statements or some possible bug.. have you tried profiling or debugging? Any attempt made like line by line tracing or throw exception?

Comment: I cant replicate this scenario in the non-prod, it is happening only in the production environment only so i cant debug it in prod.

Comment: you are saying “sometimes” issue and that too only in Production.. need to nail down as either data issue or user error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried to recreate your scenario. I added a Plugin Step on "Send" Message of Email Entity. First Image will help you explain this.

[image]

Then I create an Email with attachment and send an Email. Second image will help explain this

[image]

Now when I profile a same plugin Step, I could see plugin been triggered for Send of Email with Attachment. Image below will show this.

[image]

Summary: Yes Plugin is triggered when you attach an attachment with Email and Send it.

Comment: In the plugin code, we are getting the Acutalend field value and update in my custom field called last activity. if the Acutalend field through null no field update will happen. Does the Acutalend field value make any issues?.

Comment: I don’t think it will create any issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Date Sent** (schema name: senton) out of the box field already gives you the date and time when email was sent. Or, if you just need the date and time when email was last modified you have the **Modified On** (schema name: modifiedon) out of the box field.

Also, keep in mind that even if it worked, your logic would not give you the date and time in which the email was sent. It would give you the date and time in which the SendEmailRequest was processed by Dynamics.